# Find the equation of the hyperbola given distance between the foci and equation of asymptote

Tags: geometry

How to find the canonical equation of the hyperbola if its asymptote has equation $3x + 5y = 0$ and the distance between the foci is equal to 7?

Comment: Try working backwards: given the equation of a hyperbola, what are the equations of its asymptotes? You should be able to find a relationship between the sets of coefficients between the two equations.

Comment: $y=\pm \frac{b}{a} x$ - ?

Comment: $y=-\frac{3}{5}x$

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{5^2}-\frac{y^2}{3^2}=1$? But distance between the foci is equal $2\sqrt{34}$, not $7$ :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the hyperbola is meant to be in standard position (otherwise there’s not enough information for a unique solution), you can proceed as follows:

The slopes of the asymptotes of the hyperbola $x^2/a^2-y^2/b=1$ are $\pm b/a$, and the half-focal length $c$ satisfies $c^2=a^2+b^2$. You’ve been given the distance $2c$ and can extract the slope of the asymptote from its equation, so all that’s left is to solve this system of equations for $a$ and $b$. This will basically be a matter of scaling the numerator and denominator of the asymptote’s slope so that the sum of their squares gives the correct focal distance.

In this problem, you’ve already determined that $b/a=-3/5$, so now you need to find a scale factor $\lambda$ such that $(5\lambda)^2+(3\lambda)^2=(7/2)^2$.

Comment: $(5\lambda)^2+(3\lambda)^2=(7/2)^2$, =>, $\lambda=\pm \frac{7}{2 \cdot \sqrt{34}}$ - ?

Comment: It's amazing, thank you very much!